# Assigning a javascript variable with jquery takes just one execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

My question is very simple, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have the following code:

```
var hiddenCountryOptions = $("#HiddenCountryDropdownId option");
```

Is this code executed just once when I load the page? Or the jquery code is executed every time I use the variable?

Thanks

Comment: It is depend where you have write.

Comment: Just once. The variable will be filled with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right hand operand (right of the assignment operator) is executed only once. Simply because it's a function call, which returns an object. That return value (the object) is assigned to the variable... or at least a reference to that object is being assigned.

The [ECMA specification is quite clear about this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), in its own way, of course):

> The production AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
>
> Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> [skipping 3 & 4]
> Call PutValue(lref, rval).

As you can see, the right hand expression is evaluated first, *then* the value to which the expression was resolved is assigned.

That's the reason why you sometimes see code like this:

```
var someFunctionWithElements = (function(elem1, elem2)
{
    return function(val1, val2)
    {
        elem1.val(val1);
        elem2.val(val2);
    };
}($('#foo'), $('#bar')));
```

The closer created here is being passed 2 DOM references (wrapped in a jQ object). This way, the DOM isn't travered each time we call the `somFunctionWithElements` function...

Comment: +1 for the ECMA reference... this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Just once. `$("#HiddenCountryDropdownId option")` is a function, and once it runs and returns it's value, that value is stored in the variable `hiddenCountryOptions`. So any time you reference `hiddenCountryOptions`, you will be accessing the value returned by `$("#HiddenCountryDropdownId option")`. This isn't specific to jQuery, but is a basic feature of javascript.

Comment: Ok, great. Is there any documentation where I can confirm this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#HiddenCountryDropdownId option");
```

is a call to the jquery function, so it will execute and return a reference which will be stored in the hiddenCountryOptions variable.

Answer (score 0):

Only once. In case you want to prove it to yourself... you'll see that even after another `a` class, there are still only 2 in `adivs`: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7uVuE/

HTML

```
<div class="a">foo</div>
<div class="a">foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
```

JS

```
adivs = $(".a");
console.log(adivs.length); //2
$("div").addClass("a");
console.log(adivs.length); //still 2
```